# Element reference in dynamically added element cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError:

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a reference in my template. This element is rendered dynamically (condition doesn't matters):

```
<div #menu *ngIf="condition">
...
</div>
```

I use it in component:

```
  @ViewChild('menu')
  public set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if (content) {
      this.menuElement = content;
    }
  }
```

I have another element:
<my-component [ngStyle]="setStyles()">

I'm uding my element ref in setStyles method in my component:

```
  public setStyles(): {} {
    if (this.menuElement) {
      const menuHeight = this.menuElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
      const styles = { // some styles };
      return styles;
    }
  }
```

The problem is my tests throwns an error:
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'.
Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to help you you don't share all the relevant code, but a potential cause (and probably the most common one) for `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` can be if, for example, you're updating the value of your condition in the `AfterViewInit` life cycle hook. This is because the `AfterViewInit` is triggered after change detection runs.

If that's the case, you can move your condition logic in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. If the problem persists, I recommend setting the change detection to `OnPush`
(`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also run change detection manually..for this..

```
constructor(private cd: ChangedetectorRef){}
@ViewChild('menu')
  public set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if (content) {
      this.menuElement = content;
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```